# IOS: can not submit app identifier

Tags: ios, xcode

Am trying to register an App ID at `developer.apple.com`
I copied the the bundle identifier from Xcode and, paste it under `Explicit App ID` `Bundle ID` on the developers portal.

But i got this error message:

```
An App ID with Identifier 'io.mydomain.myapp3984430' is not available. Please enter a different string.
```

I changed the identifier and, it works then i went to Xcode to match it with the new identifier i got the same error message on Xcode.

I tried few times it seems that Xcode and the portal reserve the bundle identifier and prevent it from use and there is no way to match the bundle identifier on portal with the one on Xcode.

How could i solve this problem !

Answer (score 0):

When did you got these message? 
While archiving your app you got the message, I think you would not register your app bundle id in apple.com.
Please look for below image.
[This is app id register widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbOaU.png) 
Then you would be sure that you would use exact mobile provision proper app id.

Comment: This image you attached is exactly under developer.apple.com mentioned in the question, where i got the problem.